# JetBrains TypeScript plugin finds too many unrelated usages (WebStorm, PhpStorm, IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Given the following files:

main.ts:

```js
export const something = {
    myValue: 2,
}

function actualUsage() {
    return something.myValue
}

function unrelatedUsageCreate() {
    return { myValue: 2 }
}

function unrelatedUsageUse() {
    console.log(unrelatedUsageCreate().myValue)
}

function unrelatedUsageMapAny() {
    ;([] as Array<any>).map((v) => v.myValue)
}

function unrelatedUsageMapOtherType() {
    ;([] as Array<{ myValue: number }>).map((v) => v.myValue)
}
```

other.ts:

```
type Unrelated = {
    myValue: boolean
}

function unrelatedUsage(): Unrelated {
    return {
        myValue: false
    }
}
```

If I want to find the usages of `myValue` property of `something`, WebStorm presents me 4 references:

- `actualUsage` in `main.ts`
- `unrelatedUsage` in `other.ts`
- `unrelatedUsageCreate` in `main.ts`
- `unrelatedUsageMapAny` in `main.ts`

This is what I am seeing in the find view:

[image: find window]

And at the same time, `TypeScript` only finds the function of `actualUsage`, as seen in this [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmUAWBLMBzGBeGA3gFAykwICeAagIYA2ArkgFwwBMANEQL5FEBmDMMCjpwMGiIb0AqhBpYkACgCUhEmQBOKBprBxEKDNgB0lWoyQ8+g4aPFDtdGlCQATOQqQBhbS+VqxGQw2lC6+gTk1PRMrGwwvLwCQiJi+o5Izq4e8opyAerBoJAgdEgmdCBYShlZ7p6Kvkj+qmbRlirWyXZpMLX+OV4AsjQADgCCYBSqhWQA3EoA2gC6EhAw45qaNBQAPDRTAHwqZmNKSgBuariHMBdtFkydSbapDmBOAw1II6MA8mgkJoACoUUYFILzJarGjrTbbPaRcwxFgwMAMBAAIyBCWOp1G5yueFu92RHR4QA).

For my usage - because I am not relying on `any` types in my actual codebase - it would make much more sense to just have the `actualUsage` function's code referenced. I want WebStorm to work, just as the TypeScript Playground (or VSCode for that matter), but I cannot find the settings in the IDE to filter out the results. All the filtering settings are either applied based on get/set or file location, none of which I want.

Edit: [created a ticket out of it](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-53352)

Comment: deleted my answer after the update of your question